# How to change ruby or php version in google cloud shell console

Tags: php, ruby, shell, google-app-engine

Is it possible to change the ruby or php version used in google cloud shell console?

Specifically, I'd like like to keep the console using the ruby version used by my app engine, after I had to specifically set it to Ruby 2.42 (or whatever) in the yaml file.

Or more generally, can I customize the cloud shell to use specific language versions.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you've done so far? I'm not clear. What do you mean by "I specifically set it to Ruby 2.4.2 in the yaml file"? What do you mean by "the console"? What do you mean by "my app engine"?

Comment: [This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime) contains lots of official documentation about how ruby versions are managed by google cloud. Does that answer your question? Is there anything you're unclear about from the official documentation?

Comment: I am also grappling with the use of alternate versions of Ruby inside the Cloudshell. The cloudshell I am using right now has Ruby 2.6.5 and I can only partially get an alternate Ruby working with `rbenv`. The issue comes when I try to `bundle install` because `rbenv rehash` fails and the shell defaults to the installed version.

Comment: @IanLewis You might have had issue with the coexistence of RVM. Cloud shell comes with it already installed unless of course you used ~/.customize_environment

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by customizing my Google Cloud Shell using the environment customization script

Cloud Shell runs `$HOME/.customize_environment`, when your instance boots up. Unlike .profile or .bashrc, this script runs once when Cloud Shell boots (rather than once for each shell login).

This script runs as root and you can install any packages that you want to exist in each Cloud Shell session using Debian package management commands.

For example, if you'd like to have erlang installed on Cloud Shell, your `.customize_environment` file will look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
apt-get update
apt-get -y install erlang
```

Specifically for me, I remove RVM and use rbenv instead, personal choice of course and then set my versions in the rbenv way.